# Arrays of pointers for image encryption

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a vector p which is a vector in which I perform a permutation but I'm doing it for an image and I'm running out of memory when I'm trying to get the depermutation. I'm trying to use pointers and this is my sample. My error is: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int') for the dtr. I think I am missing something.

```
 int p[noPixels];
 for (int i = 0; i < noPixels; i++)
 p[i] = i;

 int *ptr, *dtr = new int[noPixels];

 for (int i = 0; i < noPixels; i++)
 *dtr[p[i]] = i;
```

Comment: Remove the `*` from `*dtr[p[i]] = i;`

Comment: (a) Is `noPixels` a compile-time constant? Because if not, the very first line is UB. (b) The declaration of `ptr` and `dtr` never assigns any value to `ptr`, leaving it uninitialized. (c) Are you sure you don't mean to use `std::vector` (or `std::array`, if of constant known size), which are much more intuitive and don't have quite the historical baggage?

Comment: Have you deleted the `*ptr, *dtr` ? Maybe memory leaking here.